# Vue Nuxt.js - console.log context.store object on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am using **Node** version `12.10.` and **Nuxt.js** version `2.0.0.`. I have a **Nuxt.js** app set to `universal` mode. A component has its `asyncData` lifecycle method defined as so:

```js
    export default {
        asyncData(context) {
            console.log(1);
            console.log(context);
            console.log(2);
            console.log(context.store);
            console.log(3);
        },
```

`console.log`'s `1` and `2` are fulfilled successfully. There's also a `store` object present in the `context` object:

[image]

However, it gets stuck after `console.log(2)` on logging `context.store` object by itself. Also, my CPU is on 100% and the app freezes without an error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a serialization error. wrap it in a `try/catch` and console log it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, nothing gets console'd. Everything simply hangs. I used [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) with `depth = 1` and it successfully console'd first level keys and values. However, with `depth = 2` it's unsuccessful again. I guess that the object is too large as some values get recursively referenced, hence the process chokes.